# Ansible 2.7 : How to list files from unarchive

Tags: ansible

Need to unarchive a .zip file then list the unpacked files. This is to select some pattern of files and use them in rest of the code

My playbook yaml snippet is

```
- name: uarchive the opar zip
  unarchive:
   src: "{{opar_download_path}}/opar.zip"
   dest: "{{opar_download_path}}"
   remote_src: yes
   list_files: yes
```

I am not able to find details of how to use the result from "list_files",ie how to store the list of files to a variable. I was referring below document
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html

Comment: Have you tried registering the output?

Answer (score 3):

The `list_files: yes` includes additional response attribute called `files`. For better understanding, try to print the output `unarchived_list.files`, as shown below:

```
- name: unarchive the opar zip
  unarchive:
   src: "{{opar_download_path}}/opar.zip"
   dest: "{{opar_download_path}}"
   remote_src: yes
   list_files: yes
  register: unarchived_list

- name: print unarchived folder list of files
  debug: msg="{{unarchived_list.files}}"
```

More information on registering variables can be found here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables

Comment: Since he doesn't seem to know how registering variables works, you could link him to that documentation as further reading. :)

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse I have now added the link for registering variables. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Rachel , Thank you for pointing "files" attribute. I had proceeded with shell and register , but by using unarchive list_files , I can save few lines in yaml .